# How can I take a list of server names and append a resource URI and port to ] each be

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

i have this list of ansible inventory

> ```
> servers:
>   - server01
>   - server02
>   - server03
>   - server04
> ```

***i want to do like this example I want:*** https://server01:8000;https://server02:8000],https://server03:8000;https://server04:8000

but using set_fact

Comment: what is the use case? perhaps using a template is better.

Comment: i want to use in variable inside ansible .j2

Answer (score 2):

You can use use a Jinja template to generate your desired output:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    servers:
      - server01
      - server02
      - server03
      - server04
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        urls: |-
          {% for server in servers -%}
          https://{{ server }}:8000{% if loop.index % 2 == 0 %}]{% endif %}{% if not loop.last %};{% endif %}
          {% endfor %}

    - debug:
        var: urls
```

The above playbook will output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "urls": "https://server01:8000;https://server02:8000];https://server03:8000;https://server04:8000]"
}
```

Comment: i want the url to be like this 
"https://server01:8000;https://server02:8000],https://server03:8000;https://server04:8000"
between two"" and ; after 2 url ], the last one without

Comment: Then pipe the `urls` variable to `join(';')`.

Comment: and after 2 servers server01:8000;https://server02:8000], end with this ],

Comment: See my update which I believe produces the output you want.

Comment: i can remove the ] from the last server ?

Comment: i mean the last one of my list  dont use ]

Comment: See the conditional that checks `loop.last` before adding a `;`? You can apply the same check to the `]`.

Comment: look i mean like this     "urls": "https://server01:8000;https://server02:8000],https://server03:8000;https://server04:8000"

Comment: I understand. I have explained how to do that. I think I've invested enough time in this answer; I hope it helped you make forward progress.